# Rollback fails due to no free space

Tags: sql, transactions, qt4, sqlite, rollback

I am using QSqlDatabase to access my sqlite3 database.

When the INSERT command fails because of no free disk space, the rollback is going to fail as well with next messages in my log :

```
Database error : disk I/O error
Database driver error : Unable to fetch row
Command = INSERT OR FAIL INTO Procedure ( ProcedureUUID, ProcedureGroupUUID, DefaultLocale, Author, CanBeDeleted, VersionMajor, VersionMinor, VersionMaintenance, VersionBuild ) VALUES( :ProcedureUUID, :ProcedureGroupUUID, :DefaultLocale, "User", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
```

(I am trying to log every event).

In my code, I am opening a database, starting the transaction and then I execute queries. In a case any query fails, I do a rollback.

I expected the rollback to be successful every time, but it seams like it is not the case.

Can someone explains what are the cases when the rollback fails?
And how to debug this problem.

Thanks

---

EDIT :

Can it be that I can not do the rollback, because the first SQL command failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out and I am putting an answer for future references.

If the first sql command fails, then the query seams not to be active, and the rollback is not possible. The simplest way is to check if the query is active using [isActive](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qsqlquery.html#isActive) before doing the rollback.